# Adding Java environment variables in application.properties in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am running a springboot application which requires to trust the certificate which i added in my local truststore.
For now i am setting it under run configurations options in intellij and it works.
ex->::-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=location\cacerts;-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

I was wondering is there any way to set it from application.properties file in springboot in the way we set spring properties?

Comment: why you need java environment var instead of OS environment var?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make **REST** calls, You can configure the `RestTemplate` Bean like :

```
@Configuration
public class SslConfiguration {
    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store}")
    private Resource keyStore;
    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private String keyStorePassword;

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(
                        keyStore.getURL(),
                        keyStorePassword.toCharArray()
                ).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = 
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = 
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

Check this : [Example](https://hellokoding.com/resttemplate-and-java-truststore-in-spring-boot/)

Comment: I have one doubt. Do we need to provide .Jks extension for cacerts  while using it or we can directly use it by providing path.I feel confused when i see extensions used like .truststore and .jks and cacerts has no extension at all.

Comment: No . You don't need to . See this example - [RestTemplate and Truststore](https://hellokoding.com/resttemplate-and-java-truststore-in-spring-boot/)